How to fix sister joists to this wall?
I know there are brackets for bricks but the standard ones would would cause a gap and I assume sister joists needs to be attached tightly to original joist.


Please revise to describe your project and your goal with more detail. Is that a ceiling we see below the joist? See [ask] and take the [tour] for tip.
